# Exchange 2016 mailbox with Forwarding still receiving email with "Deliver to both..." NOT checked

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016

I have multiple Exchange 2016 mailboxes that are set to forward and "Deliver message to both forwarding address and mailbox" is NOT checked.

Forwarding is working, but the mailboxes themselves still receive the emails being forwarded.

Update:

My question is, why does Exchange also deliver forwarded emails to the original recipients mailbox if the "Deliver message to both forwarding address and mailbox" is NOT checked?  Also, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the forwarding email address and re-add it with "Deliver message to both forwarding address and mailbox" unticked in EAC to see if this issue persists. Or you can use the following command to reconfigure the email forwarding.
`Set-Mailbox -Identity "UserA" -ForwardingSMTPAddress "UserB@contoso.com"`

For your reference, [Configure email forwarding for a mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients/user-mailboxes/email-forwarding?view=exchserver-2019)